# (Java)TestNG/Junit -How to Unit test a protected method in a class with no zero-argument-constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng, mockito

I have a class

```
Class abc extends base {
public abc(String a, String b)
{
super(a,b);
}

@Override
protected Object fun(String a)
{Object x;
doSomething;
return x;
}}
```

Note: There is no Zero-Argument Constructor for this class.

I am supposed to add a Unit test for the function fun(..). Is it possible using -TestNG/JUnit/Mockito ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already found a solution.
I created a test class:

```
public class testAbc extends abc {
public testAbc()
{super("x","y");}
@Override
public Object fun(String a){
Object x = super.fun(a);
}

@Test
public void testFun()
{
TestAbc t = new TestAbc();
t.fun("testString");
}


}
```

create a default constructor in the test class and make the Overridden function public.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object using the non-zero-argument constructor and unit-test the protected method if your unit test sits in the same package as the class.

If it's absolutely necessary to suppress the constructor, [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) can do it.